# How can I run my Kotlin project using Android or IntelliJ?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, dex, meta-inf

I have a Kotlin project my friend gave me.
But I don't know how to run this project.
As I see, this project structure is different from other projects.
These images show the project structure.

[image]

[image]

To run this project, I have opened this project using Android Studio and IntelliJ.
But I can't run. I don't even know which file is executable file.
Help me!
I want to know how to run this project.
Thank you for your time.
Sincerely.

Comment: Is that supposed to be an Android project? Could you post the contents of the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I can't open AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: You can open it in any other editor as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is not an Kotlin Android Project but the content of an APK file.
Therefore you don't have the source code but a compiled Android app. You can see that by the existence of `classes.dex` file, `assets`, `res` and `META-INF` directory.

That is also the reason you can not open `AndroidManifest.xml`, it is in XML binary format as it is included in APK files. Only in source projects before compiling it `AndroidManifest.xml` is a plain text XMl file.

If you want to run this "project" zip everything to an APK file, zipalign and  sign it and then install it on a phone.